# How to add an entry into Room using Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to add an entry into local DB but it's not working for me. It says `unresolved reference`.

`RoomClass.kt`

```
@Database(entities = [ApodEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun appListDao(): AppDao
}
```

`Dao.kt`

```
 @Dao
interface AppDao {

@Insert()
fun saveFavorites(item: AppEntity)
}
```

I'm trying to insert using an adapter:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
             AppDatabase.appListDao().saveFavorites(entity)
            }
```

But here `appListDao` called as unknown reference. Hope my query is cleared. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of that you must create instance of AppDabase and then on instance of it call the dao function like this:

create a file DatabaseSinglton.kt

```
object DatabaseSingleton {

    var database: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return if (database == null) {
            database = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "AppDatabase"
            ).build()

            database!!
        } else {
            database!!
        }
    }
}
```

and when your code must be change to this:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    DatabaseSingleton.getAppDatabase(
        context
    ).appListDao().saveFavorites(entity)
}
```